# QT dialog close and delete

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MainWindow and Type class.

A button in the MainWindow sends a signal to a slot with this code:

```
dialog = new QDialog(this);

Ui_type typeui;
typeui.setupUi(dialog);

dialog->show();
```

The dialog then shows. When a button is clicked on the dialog, I want to close the dialog and delete it.

I don't understand how to refer to the dialog from the dialog itself.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

You can set `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute on your dialog. This will ensure that the dialog gets deleted whenever it is closed.

Then call `close()` method in the dialog when your button is clicked.

```
dialog = new QDialog(this);

Ui_type typeui;
typeui.setupUi(dialog);

dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

dialog->show();
```

Refer to the documentation for details :

[QWidget::setAttribute ( Qt::WidgetAttribute attribute, bool on = true )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setAttribute)

[Qt::WidgetAttribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)

Answer (score 5):

First the close button is at the dialog window right, then most easy way to do it, is create a button, and connect the close() function to response the click() signal. 
like:

```
Dialog::Dialog(){
   // other code
   QPushButton *closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("Close"));
    connect(closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));
   // other code
}
```

Under the Qt/examples/dialog projects are good reference for your question. check it out.

Comment: So I'd need to create a private slot called close? And inside that, what line of code would I use to refer to the dialog? I'm a bit confused in general how to communicate between variables etc between the mainwindow and the dialog!

Comment: QDialog inherits QWidget and QWidget already provides `close()` slot.

Comment: Ahhh I see, ok a better way to explain why I need inline code is because when I click the button on the form to close, it's not a close button but an action button and the form needs to close after some code that does something else first.

Comment: Murat is right, click() and close() both are native defined by QWidget, you don't have to that.

Comment: Ok...the button is attached to a private slot that processes some other code before it would then close the dialog. If I just call a close() on the button, it won't process the code the dialog is open for in the first place! So the button is to carry out code THEN close the dialog.

Comment: Connect clicked() signal of your button to your slot THEN call close at the end of that slot.

Comment: That's what I meant, it's quite simply 'close();' to close the dialog?

Comment: the Dialog/configdialog has a similar example for your case.

Comment: I'm taking a look as there are two classes trying to work with each other. Bizarrely, this code....connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close())); ...doesn't close the dialog? That is a pushButton on the dialog and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: make sure which pushButton You connect to. make another QPushButton object, instead like to ui

Comment: Yeah I did, it isn't even showing the next one on the UI!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to get input from a *modal* dialog is `QDialog::exec()`. This may handle everything you need.

Comment: I have a QStringList in my MainWindow class and a QTextEdit in my dialog class. When I click a button, I'm creating a private slot to add the textedit to the stringlist. My issue is how do I add to the qstringlist from the mainwindow when in a function in the dialog window? I would then need to 'refresh' the mainwindow UI. I just need an explanation for that and I'll be well away!

Comment: One (not necessarily the best) way is to pass the main window pointeri in the parent constructor parameter and access the the (public) string list through the pointer.

Comment: Are other ways more complicated? Could you provide any code examples? Just need a push in the right direction to get this understanding.

Comment: I am just on my mobile phone, used to do this 10 yoears ago with qt3 and your description is not 100 clear. Byt in your dialog code you can write something `parent -> theStringlist << stringToAdd`.