# Does closing a QDialog window delete its dynamically added UI elements?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdialog

I have a QDialog window in my application and I am dynamically adding a QComboBox for its layout through this code

*Orderdialog.cpp*

```
void Orderdialog::addElements()
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    msgComboBox = new QComboBox();
    lbl = new QLabel();
    lbl->setText("Message");
    ui->formLayout->addRow(lbl,msgComboBox);    
}
```

(msgComboBox & lbl is defined in the header file)

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831431/qt-dialog-close-and-delete) setting an attritubte will delete the dialog object when its *close()* event is executed.

What I want to know is whether it deletes these dynamically added *msgComboBox* & *lbl* or do I need to manually delete them in the destructor of Orderdialog class?

Comment: what is `msgAliasComboBox`?

Comment: sorry It was a mistake, I corrected it

Comment: Put a `qDebug()` in a child's destructor and you'll check that easily enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Qt:

- When the `QObject`s are destroyed they destroy their children.
- When a QWidget is closed, it is not deleted, except when the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute is established.

A QWidget is a QObject so it also meets the first point, so that a QWidget is the children of another QWidget there are at least 3 possibilities:

- You pass the parent QWidget in the constructor.
- You use the `setParent()` method.
- And when you establish it through a layout since your parent will be the widget to which the layout was established.

In the case of `lbl` and `msgComboBox`  being passed to a layout this will be the childrens of the `QWidget` that was established, as I do not know the .ui could not say who is his parent but I can say that there is a relationship of kinship with the window.

So when the window is destroyed your children will also be destroyed, and these children will destroy their children, so lbl and msgComboBox will be destroyed, so you only have to `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose)` so that lbl, msgComboBox and the same Orderdialog are deleted when the window is closed.

Comment: so If I add `delete msgComboBox` and `delete lbl` after the `delete ui` will it cause an exception?

Comment: Although the layout re-parents the widgets, as a good practice I'd just set the correct parent on widget creation; this makes sure they are correctly deleted in case of exception, and getting in the habit makes sure you don't risk leaking widgets that may happen not to be added to a layout. Also, it's a favor you do to the future maintainers of your code - reading the code and seeing widgets being created without a parent rang several bells in my head, and I had to double-check if they were explicitly re-parented/deleted later and if indeed adding to a layout does re-parent.

Comment: @Oshada does not cause any exception, Qt verifies the existence of the object

Comment: @MatteoItalia Although what you point out is correct, I often do not establish the relationship of kinship since I always use the layouts. :-)

Comment: @Oshada: you will get a crash (really undefined behavior) if the parent of the widget does get deleted by `delete ui`; this essentially boils down to whether `formLayout` is a layout applied to a widget (=which gets destroyed by `delete ui`) or to the dialog (which is still alive after `delete ui`). Notice that instead doing `delete lbl` before `delete ui` it will always work, as `QObject` automatically removes itself from the object tree when destroyed, so its parent no longer sees it as a child, and avoids the double free.

Comment: @eyllanesc: Qt cannot verify that the object is still alive to be deleted unless you use a `QPointer` (which is automatically invalidated at `QObject` destruction). If OP is using naked pointers Qt cannot verify a thing - if the object has been deleted by his parent all you have now is a dangling pointer, which will lead to unpredictable results when deleted again.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You are right, I am assuming many things that are already natural to me, such as the use of QXXXPointer, but in modern C++, we rarely use naked pointers.

Comment: @eyllanesc if you establish proper kinship relationships you don't really need smart pointers for `QObject`, unless in really particular cases.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well, what problems could the use or abuse of QPointer bring?

Comment: @eyllanesc: nothing tragic AFAIK - a bit of code bloat, reduced performance on object destruction, slightly reduced performance on object access. But again, the biggest problem is in communication with other mantainers of your project: if I see a `QPointer` I immediately suspect that there's some "strange" lifetime thing going on (and thus you needed some way to check if the object was still alive), and have to investigate it; it's exactly as if you used `std::shared_ptr` for everything: it does work, but it makes the reader suspect that there's ownership sharing going on.

Comment: Let's add that in the examples of the doc the dialog are often modal and created on the stack in a very simple slot, in such case you don't need the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag.